XDocument - Convert Open and Close Tags to Self-Closing Tag
NOTE: This is NOT a semantic question. This isn't asking about what self closing tags mean. This is about doing the OPPOSITE with XDocument than what is mentioned in this example post with C#:
A
Remove self-closing tags (e.g. />) in an XmlDocument
Please read this question thoroughly before linking to a non-applicable duplicate.
I'm writing this because I've found so many posts on here and elsewhere that ask about a good way to change self-closing tags in a C# XDocument object to an open and close tag with an empty value.
I want to do the opposite. I want to change this:
<GovtID id="1"></GovtID>
to this:
<GovtID id="1"/>
I want to preserve all attributes and their values that were in the element from before, EXCEPT empty values.
Here's the latest thing I've tried:
private static void CleanUpXElements(XDocument doc)
{
    foreach (XElement childElement in
        from x in doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
        where x.Value == string.Empty
        select x)
    {
        childElement.ReplaceWith(new XElement(childElement.Name.LocalName, childElement.Attributes()));
    };
}

However, when I use this approach, I get a Null Exception when the child element in question gets replaced this way.
Is there a way I can do this without throwing a Null Reference Exception? I see the element change to a self closing tag, but then the Null Exception happens.

There is no semantic difference between the two forms at the XML level, and you should not impose or accept an artificial difference because doing so impedes interoperability.

I completely concur with @kjhughes. Still, you can try XSLT transformation with a so called Identity Transform pattern to achieve what you need.

@kjhughes this is actually something I'm trying to do to use XMLSerializer to convert the XML to an object

@YitzhakKhabinsky that is something I've considered and I would be open to trying if I can't think of any other way

Also, if we shouldn't be treating those tags differently semantically, why is that question I linked in this one something that is answered with a how-to?

@kjhughes - I disagree this is a duplicate.  Even if the two "Empty" forms are semantically identical there can be methods that treat them differently.  For instance XNode.DeepEquals() treats them differently.  Converting from one representation to another is a reasonable, albeit unusual, requirement.  See e.g. How can I stop empty XML elements self-closing using XmlDocument in C#?.

What @dbc just said

@KieranOjakangas: Conversion to an object should work with both forms, so there should be no reason to convert between them.  I suspect you're presenting an XY-problem in that you mistakenly believe your real goal to require conversion between these equivalent forms and you're presenting a misguided method as your actual goal.

@dbc: Any "equals" that distinguishes between those two forms is fundamentally broken (and probably mistakes many other non-differences as well).  There are lexical motivations such as those behind XML normalization that warrant attention to the distinction, but that's not what's presented here.

@kjhughes guess what - you're right. I got the answer I was looking for here, but I'm still having the same issue with XmlSerializer - I'll have to keep digging around to find the true problem. One thing at a time!

@KieranOjakangas - is your real problem that GovtID is defined in C# to be an int? or int and XmlSerializer throws when deserializing an element with an empty value?  If so see Deserializing empty xml attribute value into nullable int property using XmlSerializer.

@dbc Yup. You nailed it. I still think this might be a useful question for someone that is trying to write self closing tags for a different purpose. So I still appreciate your answer.

I think your problem may be that you are modifying the document's element tree while iterating through it, causing the iterator to throw an exception when it tries to proceed past the modification.
As an alternative, you could iterate through the elements and, for every element that has no child elements and an empty value, completely remove all child nodes:
public static void CleanUpXElements(this XDocument doc)
{
    foreach (XElement childElement in
             from x in doc.Descendants()
             where !x.IsEmpty && !x.Elements().Any() && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value)
             select x)
    {
        childElement.RemoveNodes();
    };
}

This avoids modifying the element tree while iterating through it and results in <GovtID id="1" />
Demo fiddle here.
Be aware that, as noted by kjhughes, the two empty element forms <GovtID id="1"></GovtID> and <GovtID id="1" /> are semantically identical. As such it should not be necessary to convert one form to the other, and any code that depends on the difference between them is likely broken.
Finally, if your underlying problem is that

You are deserializing using XmlSerializer.
The value of <GovtID> is defined to be an int or int? or Guid? or other primitive (non-string) value type in your data model.
The serializer is throwing an exception attempting to deserialize the empty value <GovtID></GovtID>.

Then see Deserializing empty xml attribute value into nullable int property using XmlSerializer.  This answer by bvdb to Self-closing tags in XML files would also apply.

This definitely gave me what I was looking for - thanks!

When you help with tactics at the expense of strategy, in the end you've caused more harm than good.
